# Phrasing of "this=that" sentence?

Tags: grammar, verbs, commas

What is the best way to phrase and punctuate this type of "this = that" sentence?

No noise was detected, indicating that the room was empty.

No noise was detected, which indicated that the room was empty.

Thanks,
EM

Comment: Almost related: I'm wondering why you are focusing solely on the use of `which` when the use of `that` in this sentence seems at least as optional. I might prefer "No noise was detected, indicating the room was empty." from a minimalist perspective.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I'd use:

> No noise was detected, suggesting an empty room.

'Indicates' seems a bit too certain for a mere absence of sound.

Answer (score 0):

Those are both perfectly fine.

I prefer the second just because the first seems to spell things out a little too much, as if assuming the reader must be dim, but in another sentence with the same structure I might prefer it precisely because it spells things out that slight bit more.

Answer (score 0):

Both of your sentences are phrased and punctuated correctly.

Here's a couple of alternatives, removing "that":

> No noise was detected, indicating the room was empty.
>
> No noise was detected, which indicated the room was empty.

I prefer the first of these alternatives, since it's a bit simpler (as BlackVegetable mentioned).